# How to properly insert <video> tag into html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just getting started here with javascript and have made this.

I have made a codepen that shows the two issues I am having

1) there are two duplicate videos being loaded in, when I delete one of the video tags it prevents the randomize button from working or any video from loading up. I am only trying to have one video load in.

2) In the codepen I have a button that clicks to randomize but instead I am trying to have the video wrapped with an tag so that the video can be clicked to initiate the randomize. Whenever I try and do this I get an undefined error or the videos will not load in =/

Play video

```
<div class="video-label"></div> <!-- loads in top video (only want one video) --> 

<video loop autoplay> <!-- loads in bottom video (only want one video) -->
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

If you click on the codepen you will hopefully be able to see where the two videos are being loaded in and where the click tag is. Any help is greatly appreciated!! I've been trying to figure it out all night :/

Here is the codepen

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/H0BB5/pen/JoWMyp)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the codepen code? It's saying "enter code hereCodepen"

Comment: It's up now! My bad haha, thanks for letting me know :) Too stressed about this I cant think straight

Comment: Why do you post the same stuff twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957349/how-to-load-object-inside-of-an-a-tag <- That would be a reason for a BIG Downvote

Comment: never had this up until after the downvote. Been waiting all night for an answer on this, no one checks downvoted posts and it's not even clear why it was downvoted to me..

Comment: Did you consider using a third party HTML5 Video player such as Sublime Video Player (http://docs.sublimevideo.net/javascript-api/usage)? It would help you to manage this kind of stuff by providing some effective methods. Plus you will have all necessary tools to provide fallback for non-HTML5 compliant browsers..

Comment: I am still working on my javascript so I was trying to keep this as vanilla as possible. Besides i've gotten so close to getting it finished I just can't figure out what this last issue is, it's nearly all finished.

Comment: There is an error in your code, try changing the second line in your videos array: { category: 'landscape',  sources: [ { type: 'video/webm', src: 'http://zippy.gfycat.com/SpottedDefensiveAbalone.webm'  }, { type: 'video/mp4', src: 'http://zippy.gfycat.com/SpottedDefensiveAbalone.mp4' } ] },  It seems to work now..

Comment: sorry that was an unrelated fix for the codepen. 
The issue is the javascript displaying two videos instead of just one :(

Comment: Which one do you want do keep? First or second one?

Comment: The first one because the second one doesnt randomize when clicked

Answer (score 2):

You can create a html5 video tag using javascript by following this logic:

```
var videoelement = document.createElement("video");
videoelement.setAttribute("id", "video1");

var sourceMP4 = document.createElement("source"); 
sourceMP4.type = "video/mp4";
sourceMP4.src = "http://zippy.gfycat.com/SpottedDefensiveAbalone.mp4";
videoelement.appendChild(sourceMP4);

var sourceWEBM = document.createElement("source"); 
sourceWEBM.type = "video/webm";
sourceWEBM.src = "http://zippy.gfycat.com/MinorGregariousGrub.webm";
videoelement.appendChild(sourceWEBM);

$('.video-label').html(videoelement);
var video = document.getElementById("video1");
video.play();
```

This code is creating a video tag and including it into your div (.video-label), then the video starts automatically. This is working without the random stuff (the same url is used everytime), so you can update it at your convenience. Try to remove the video in you html file, it works now:

```
<video loop autoplay>
      Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

Here is a link where you can download your code updated with working solution (without randomization):

http://tests.krown.ch/Codepen.zip

Also when you click on your video div (.video-label), the video tag will be deleted and created back (but with same url, you just need to update video url with your randomize stuff)

Comment: If you are using plain javascript why are you finishing with JQuery, good answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this line you find any `video` tags on the page and try to copy it's content into `div`:

```
var $video = $('video');
...
$('.video-label').html($video.get(0).outerHTML);
```

But if you delete `video` from the page there will be nothing to copy. You need to [move](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEWeqg) `video` tag inside `div` in first place. Or create it dynamically, not by copying, when user clicks link.